# Jest returns a table not found error with sqlite

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, sequelize.js

I've written a set of tests and am using Sequelize as my ORM and Jest as my test runner.

My Sequelize config looks like this:

```
{
  "development": {
    "dialect": "sqlite",
    "storage": "dev.sqlite"
  },
  "test": {
    "dialect": "sqlite",
    "storage": ":memory:"
  },
}
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
    "test": "jest --setupFiles dotenv/config",
    "pretest": "yarn migrate && yarn seed",
    "migrate": "cd server && npx sequelize-cli db:migrate",
    "migrate:reset": "cd server && npx sequelize-cli db:migrate:undo:all --env test && npm run migrate --env test",
    "seed": "cd server && npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all --env test",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect node_modules/.bin/jest",
```

My jest setup files simply ensure that the Node environment is `test`.

Everything works as expected and the migrations run with no problems, as do the seed files. But when the tests start I get the following:

`SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: Users`. This is the same for every table used.

I suspect the problem is in the fact that when a connection closes, the in-memory database is terminated so I tried running the database migrations and seed on a per-test basis but this didn't work. Likewise for using an actual `test.sqlite` file.

Any advice?

An example of my Registration test:

```
import { getMaxTokenAge } from '../../../utils/auth'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import mutation from '../register'
import models from '../../../models/'

import query from '../getUser'

describe('register', () => {
  describe('resolver', () => {
    const res = {
      cookie: jest.fn(),
    }
    const userInfo = {
      email: 'test@example.com',
      firstName: 'First',
      lastName: 'Last',
      phone: '0123456789',
      orgName: 'Org Name',
      organization: 'none',
      password: 'secret123',
      newOrganization: {
        name: 'Org Name',
        type: 'buyer',
      },
    }

    test('guests can register', async () => {
      // Get the role and type of a buyer
      const buyerRole = await models.UserRole.findOne({
        where: {
          name: 'buyer',
        },
        raw: true,
      })

      const someBuyerType = await models.UserType.findOne({
        where: {
          name: 'somebuyer',
        },
        raw: true,
      })

      // Take the ids for role and type and add them to our user info to submit
      userInfo.role = someRole.id
      userInfo.type = someType.id

      await mutation({}, userInfo, {
        context: {},
        models,
        req: {},
        res,
      })

      expect(
        await query({}, { email: userInfo.email }, `{ email, id }`),
      ).toMatchSnapshot({
        createdAt: expect.any(Date),
        updatedAt: expect.any(Date),
        id: expect.any(String),
        password: expect.any(String),
        UserRoleId: expect.any(String),
        UserTypeId: expect.any(String),
      })

      expect(res.cookie).toHaveBeenCalledWith('token', expect.any(String), {
        maxAge: getMaxTokenAge(),
        httpOnly: true,
      })
    })

    test('throws an error when trying to register with an email that belongs to an existing user', async () => {
      models.User.findOne = sinon.stub().resolves(true)

      await expect(
        mutation({}, userInfo, {
          models,
          req: {},
          res,
        }),
      ).rejects.toThrowErrorMatchingInlineSnapshot(
        `"A user already exists with this email address."`,
      )
    })
  })
})
```

and registration code:

````
/**
 * @param {*} parent
 * @param {string} email
 * @param {string} password
 * @param {*} args
 * @param {*} context
 *
 * @example
 * ```
 * register(
 *  email: "${user.email}"
 *  password: "secret123"
 *  organization: "none"
 *  firstName: "${user.firstName}"
 *  lastName: "${user.lastName}"
 *  phone: "0123456789"
 *   newOrganization: {
 *     name: "${user.orgName}"
 *     type: "buyer"
 *   }
 * ) {
 *  token
 *  user {
 *   email
 *  }
 * }
 * ```
 */
const register = async (
  root,
  {
    email,
    password,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    phone,
    organization,
    newOrganization,
    role,
    type,
  },
  { models, res, req },
) => {
  const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)

  const exists = await models.User.findOne({ where: { email } })

  if (exists) {
    throw new DatabaseError('A user already exists with this email address.')
  }

  const user = await models.User.create({
    email,
    password: encryptedPassword,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    phone,
  })

  await user.setUserRole(role)

  await user.setUserType(type)

  const token = jwt.sign(
    {
      userId: user.id,
    },
    process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  )


  res.cookie('token', token, {
    maxAge: getMaxTokenAge(),
    httpOnly: true,
  })

  req.user = user

  return user
}

export default register
````

Comment: Please provide the minimal completed reproducible code under test

Comment: Updated answer with code.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problem with testing my db-tables and models. I've solved it by adding this code:

```
    await User.sync({ force: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect the problem is in the fact that when a connection closes, the in-memory database is terminated so I tried running the database migrations and seed on a per-test basis but this didn't work.

I agree. in-memory databases won't be available for testing with sequelize-cli and Jest.

That said, as @Danny suggested, it's still possible to use the in-memory database via `sync` function. The following is how I did this. Hopefully this will be helpful for someone.

Here's how I instantiate sequelize and export it

```
// sequelize.ts

import { Sequelize, Dialect } from 'sequelize';

import config from 'config/config.js';

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

let sequelize;
if (env === 'test') {
  sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:', { logging: false });
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(/* for dev/prod envorionment */);
}

export { sequelize };
```

Here's how I pass it to `db` object, through which all the models will become available.

```
// db/index.ts

import { Role } from 'db/models/role';
import { User } from 'db/models/user';

import { sequelize } from 'db/sequelize';

const db: { [key: string]: any } = {
  Role: Role(sequelize),
  User: User(sequelize),
  // You can put other models
};

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;

export default db;
```

Then, use the `sync` function of the `db` object before running tests.

```
// user.service.spec.ts

import db from 'db';

describe('UserService', () => {

  beforeAll(async () => {
    await db.sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    db.User.create({ /* create a mock user instance */ });
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await db.sequelize.close();
  });

  it('should ___ ', async () => {
    // test User however you want
  });
});
```

Comment: This helped me so much. I didn't `export default db` but instead `export default sequelize` after associating models and seeding the db, and in my tests just `sequelize.sync()` / `sequelize.close()`.